# user account url without prefix

Tags: url, user-accounts, api-design, url-design

I try to create a website contain user account system,
the user profile page, url path is `domain.com/:username`. I don't want to use prefix like `domain.com/user/:username` .

So I have to find strings avoid user register,

1. My website other url path first slot is `domain.com/filter/`, `domain.com/search/`, `domain.com/p/`, ... I will add these.
2. I read about other website doc like [google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33386?hl=en) [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/105399436216001) .. 
   e.g. facebook are specific list can't contain generic terms or extensions (ex: .com, .net).
   is there any other strategy (keyword not allow), suggestion I should know and use to avoid future problem?